# Spring Infinispan - Setting expiry time for cached objects

Tags: caching, infinispan, spring-cache

We are currently using below. It's quite old, but cannot upgrade to higher version now

```
`
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
     <artifactId>infinispan-spring3</artifactId>
     <version>6.4.0.Final-redhat-4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-client-hotrod</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0.Final-redhat-4</version>
  </dependency>
`
```

We have modified our code from something with a direct JDG implementation (as shown below) to SpringRemoteCacheManager in an XML based configuration file and are using Spring cache:advice to define cacheable, cahce-put, cache-evict methods.

See Current code where we have control to add expiry time. We want to do similar thing with Spring - Infinispan as well. With Spring - Infinispan we do not write any application code that puts/gets objects in/from cache as its handled by Spring annotations (@Cacheable / @CachePut)
Appreciate if anyone can provide any pointers

```
RemoteCache<Object, Object> cache =  jdgRemoteCacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
cache.put(keyName, object, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Those versions are product versions. You should check with Red Hat professional support for specific questions on those.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Spring Cache support doesn't provide such methods (see the [Javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html)). So it seems the only way is to use the `RemoteCache` API provided by Infinispan.

Perhaps you could implement your own `@Cacheable` annotation and implement all the functionality you need. But that's a Spring question really...