# Infinispan lifespan settings in version 6.4.0

Tags: caching, infinispan

Infinispan 9 provides the below methods to set an expiry at overall cache level. Is there an way to do this using Infinispan 6.4.0 (this does not have expiration() method)

Infinispan 9:

```
org.infinispan.client.hotrod.configuration.ConfigurationBuilder

new ConfigurationBuilder().expiration()
  .lifespan(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .build();
```

Spring cache + Infinispan 6 (remote cache manager)

```
<bean id="remoteCacheManager" class="org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager">  
        <constructor-arg name="configuration" ref="cacheConfiguration" />  
        <constructor-arg type = "boolean" value="true" />  
</bean>

<bean id="springRemoteCacheManager" class="org.infinispan.spring.provider.SpringRemoteCacheManager">
        <constructor-arg name="nativeCacheManager" ref="remoteCacheManager" />
</bean>

@Bean(name="cacheConfiguration") 
...{
  org.infinispan.client.hotrod.configuration.ConfigurationBuilder builder = new org.infinispan.client.hotrod.configuration.ConfigurationBuilder();  
  for(String jdgServer : jdgServers) {
    builder.addServer()
             .host(jdgServer)
             .port(port)
             .connectionTimeout(connectionTimeout);
  return builder.build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have crossed up the different ConfigurationBuilder classes. The one you are looking for is [org.infinispan.cache.configuration.ConfigurationBuilder](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/6.0.x/core/src/main/java/org/infinispan/configuration/cache/ConfigurationBuilder.java). Infinispan 6.x has the expiration element there. The [org.infinispan.client.hotrod.configuration.ConfigurationBuilder](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/6.0.x/client/hotrod-client/src/main/java/org/infinispan/client/hotrod/configuration/ConfigurationBuilder.java) you referenced is for configuring the remote client.

As always, it is recommended to upgrade to a more recent version though :)

Comment: Yes, you'r right.  Unfortunately we cannot upgrade to a newer version. We are trying to create a remote cache manager and using Spring cache abstraction. Is there a way i can set cache level or object level expiry time for objects. See my cache manager bean definitions updated in my original post.

Comment: This sounds like the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50397558/spring-infinispan-setting-expiry-time-for-cached-objects. In that case you need to use API methods to set the expiration per invocation https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/9.3/apidocs/org/infinispan/commons/api/BasicCache.html#put-K-V-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: Yes, thanks. Problem we are facing boils down to the query you posted. But, challenge here is we are now using Spring cache abstraction (@cacheable etc) so we do not explicitly call put methods to add to cache and hence cannot set expiry time. For now, we are using server level JDG configuration <distributed-cache>.. to set the eviction and expiration times. We were hoping to do this programatically with Spring Cache + Infinispan 6 combination (Remote cache)